# How to inject pod environment variables values into React app on runtime?

Tags: reactjs, kubernetes

Running pods have some environment variables defined inside, for example:

```
/ # printenv
REACT_APP_ENV_VARIABLE=Variable from Kube!
REDIS_SERVICE_PORT=6379
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT=443
KUBERNETES_PORT=tcp://10.38.0.1:443
REDIS_PORT=tcp://10.38.61.225:6379
REDIS_PORT_6379_TCP_ADDR=10.38.61.225
HOSTNAME=playground-pod
PLAYGROUND_SERVICE_SERVICE_HOST=10.38.0.53
REDIS_PORT_6379_TCP=tcp://10.38.61.225:6379
PLAYGROUND_SERVICE_SERVICE_PORT=80
PLAYGROUND_SERVICE_PORT=tcp://10.38.0.53:80
PLAYGROUND_SERVICE_PORT_80_TCP_ADDR=10.38.0.53
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_PROTO=tcp
PLAYGROUND_SERVICE_PORT_80_TCP_PORT=80
PLAYGROUND_SERVICE_PORT_80_TCP_PROTO=tcp
REACT_APP_ENV_VARIABLE_TWO=192.168.1.12
PLAYGROUND_SERVICE_PORT_80_TCP=tcp://10.38.0.53:80
```

How should I configure a React app like this one:

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <p>
            <code>ENV. VARIABLE: </code> {x.REACT_APP_ENV_VARIABLE}
        </p>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

to read and inject some of the variables present in the pod?

The main reason I want to know it, is dynamic update of e.g. backend or Redis URLs - they might change when the app is restarted, rescheduled, etc.

My first approach was using a `config.json` file imported to the app, but this way I can't import dynamic values generated by running pods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Harsh Manvar suggested (thanks a lot!), the `react-dotenv` library can be used, but just adding it to the project is not enough.

Firstly, you have to follow all steps described in [react-dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dotenv) documentation (adding `.env` file to your project, editing `package.json` file).

In my case, `.env` file looked like this:

```
REACT_APP_DEPLOY_SETUP='__dps__'
REACT_APP_PORT='__prt__'
REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL='__bur__'
```

These are just placeholders for real values that will be added during runtime.

Having the `.env` file ready, `npm` scripts prepended with `react-dotenv` command, and the variables whitelisted (as described in the library documentation), you can build your app image.

When the image is ready, add it to the `kubernetes` pod config file and replace your variables' placeholders with real values, like this:

```yaml
[...]
spec:
  containers:
  - name: plg-frontend
    image: localhost:5000/frontend:1.22
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
    command:
    - sh
    - -c
    args:
    - sed -i "s/__prt__/$REACT_APP_PORT/g" /usr/share/nginx/html/env.js;
      sed -i "s/__bur__/http:\/\/$BACKEND_SERVICE_HOST/g" /usr/share/nginx/html/env.js;
      sed -i "s/__dps__/$REACT_APP_DEPLOY_SETUP/g" /usr/share/nginx/html/env.js;
      nginx -g 'daemon off;'
    env:
    - name: REACT_APP_DEPLOY_SETUP
      value: "development"
    - name: REACT_APP_PORT
      value: "5089"
```

What happened up there, was replacing placeholder values with actual values:

- `$BACKEND_SERVICE_HOST` is an environment variable that exists in the pod and can be read from the running container,
- `$REACT_APP_DEPLOY_SETUP` is a regular string defined by user,
- `$REACT_APP_PORT` is an integer value (it has to be in quotes, like strings!).

And the replacing happened with `sed` command (or rather: `sh -c "sed -i ..."`). All of the commands are chained, so don't forget about semicolons at the end of each argument.

All of the replacements were made in `/usr/share/nginx/html/env.js` file, which is created by `react-dotenv` library in project root. The actual location depends on where you mounted your build image (it's defined in `Dockerfile`).

Lastly, `nginx` command is called, since this is the final command invoked in image's `Dockerfile`. Without this explicit call, the command from the `Dockerfile` would be overwritten with the commands related to the pod container and, in this case, `nginx` wouldn't start your app.

After the pod is started, you can check whether the variables are present in the container:

```
kubectl exec <pod-name> -- printenv | grep REACT_APP
```

But it doesn't mean they were read by your app during runtime. To see if they were changed to the values from the pod definition, you can either `exec` running pod container and preview the `env.js` file or add some console logging in the app code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the library [dot-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dotenv)

```
import React from "react";
import env from "react-dotenv";

export function MyComponent() {
  return <div>{env.REACT_APP}</div>;
}
```

while in deployment you can pass secret from secret and configmap

```
spec:
      containers:
        - name: example-site
          image: example/app:v1
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
          env:
          - name: REACT_APP
            value: "123456"
```

> The main reason I want to know it, is dynamic update of e.g. backend
> or Redis URLs - they might change when the app is restarted,
> rescheduled, etc.

Above scenario fit well with your requirement, instead of using the `config.json`.

You can pass multiple values to deployment using configmap and secrets.

Comment: Variables don't get read from the pod. I've set two variables: both are defined initially in the `.env` file. Both are whitelisted in `package.json`. Then, one gets overwritten while building docker image (and it displays its `Dockerfile` value in the React app), meanwhile the second one isn't changed anywhere and the initial value is finally displayed in the React app. I tried setting up variables via `env` and `ConfigMap` - none of these worked. And of course, both variables are visible when `printenv` inside the running pod gets called.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to comment under someone else's answer yet, but just to add to @AbreQueVoy's answer:

I had trouble with one of my variables: It was a URL.

---

```
sed -i "s/__prt__/$REACT_APP_URL/g" /usr/share/nginx/html/env.js;
```

The first character after the s (/) is our separator: Thus SED freaked out when getting a URL. I simply replaced the / and changed the separator to a , like so:

```
args:
    - sed -i "s,__prt__,$REACT_APP_PORT,g" /usr/share/nginx/html/env.js;
      sed -i "s,__bur__,http:\/\/$BACKEND_SERVICE_HOST,g" /usr/share/nginx/html/env.js;
      sed -i "s,__dps__,$REACT_APP_DEPLOY_SETUP,g" /usr/share/nginx/html/env.js;
      nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```

I did find [this tutorial](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) useful for learning a bit about SED.